# How do you ssh into an D-Link router?

Tags: router, ssh, wireless-router, adsl-router

I was able to telnet into an D-Link router in the default state using admin:admin, but using the same username and password, I wasn't able to ssh into it (from the same LAN) eventhough ssh is open.

Comment: If you are using the default firmware you enable ssh and then ssh into the router like any other host.  If you are using third-party firmware you enable ssh and then ssh into the router like any other host. If you cannot enable ssh then you will be unable to ssh into the router.  You being able to telnet into the router does not mean it supports ssh.

Comment: @Ramhound having scanned it with nmap (found ssh open), and being able to get the password prompt for ssh, I thought that ssh is enabled, isn't it ?

Comment: The username and password you tried, if ssh is enabled, should have worked.  It's possible the username and password are different, if it is, that would be found on the configuration page for the router.  Have you checked the manual for the router?

Comment: Had you looked into a manual or a user guide online to that specific router? I believe SSH sometimes comes packed with a different user/pass... I suggest you either post the model or look it up online

Comment: "I wasn't able to ssh into it" Specifically happens when you try? What error messages do you get?

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I managed to ssh to my home D-Link ADSL-Router. My model is `DSL-2740U`.

```
ssh -o KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -c 3des-cbc admin@192.168.1.1
```

The username/password is the same as you enter to login to the web panel.

Comment: this worked flawlessly , and now I'm able to automate some configs using Python + Wexpect!

Answer (score 1):

I have a **D-Link DSL-2750U H/W rev. U1** with firmware version *ME_1.11* and found that the SSH option simply doesn't exist anywhere in the router's web configuration.

[image: Web Config -> Access Controls -> Services]

But `nmap` does indeed list the ssh port as open.

[image: Nmap scan report for port 22]

After some trial and error, I was able to find out that both, **the default username and password for the ssh login are *root***.

[image: SSH login from PowerShell]

I couldn't find an option anywhere that allows me to change this default username/password or disable SSH. (If someone does, you are most welcome, because this SSH access is quite useless otherwise.) Nor did I find any official documentation anywhere that mentions about this SSH feature or the default credentials. (If someone does, please put a link here)

Apparently, the ssh-access is a left-out feature that exists only in some firmware versions in some older D-Link DSL routers. If someone else is able to confirm this works for them, please put your router model and firmware version here.

Comment: It seems a newer H/W revision of the same router (2750U/IN/I with F/W IN_R_01.00.09) also has SSH access enabled with no option to turn it off: Someone posted about it in the [D-Link forums](http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=74446.0)

Comment: use `passwd` command to set the password or `adduser` to create a new user

Answer (score 0):

I had to configure my ~/.ssh/config for my D-Link N310 with the following to be able to connect:

```
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512
Ciphers aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr

User username # it depends on your login; this one only for understanding

PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```